# Jquery mobile input type file not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

I am developing a web application which has input type file in form.In chrome browser when i select file page get refresh automatically so the file is actually not selected. it works fine in firefox browser. Any idea why it not working in chrome  ?

Any one has idea why this happening ?

This is the form

```
 <div data-role="content" >
    <form  id="photoForm" class="file_upload" >
          <label data-role="button" class="file-upload">
            Select Photo
            <input  type="file" name="photo_upload_file" id="photo_upload_file" value="" >
        </label>
          <textarea name="photo_comment" id="photo_comment"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Some code would be helpful in finding your bug...

Comment: If you copy and paste that code into jsFiddle, it works fine in Chrome. There must be something else going on in your webpage.